# Bottom content hidden by keyboard in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a bottom textField when i click it the keyboard shows up and hide the content.
I tried using: `padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets` and `resizetoavoidbottominset` but nothing works.

My widget tree is: Scaffold->SafeArea->Padding->SingleChildScrollView->Form

```
Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 20.0.w,
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
```

[image: before i click on the contact number]

[image: after i click on the contact number]

In the code below i tried to put my file structure and widget tree for the problematic page:
main.dart

```
 runApp(
ScreenUtilInit(
  designSize: const Size(screenWidth, screentHeight),
  minTextAdapt: true,
  splitScreenMode: true,
  useInheritedMediaQuery: true,
  builder: (_, child) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: child: const MyApp()),
    );
  },
),
```

);

myApp:

```
PersistentTabView(
  context,
  controller: controller,
  screens: buildScreens(),
  items: navBarsItems(),
  confineInSafeArea: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
  stateManagement: true,
  hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
  decoration: NavBarDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    colorBehindNavBar: Colors.white,
  ),
  popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
  popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
  itemAnimationProperties: const ItemAnimationProperties(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    curve: Curves.ease,
  ),
  screenTransitionAnimation: const ScreenTransitionAnimation(
    animateTabTransition: true,
    curve: Curves.ease,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  ),
  navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style6,
  onItemSelected: (index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 1:
        BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context).add(
          const InitializeAccountEvent(
            uiTitle: 'orders',
          ),
        );
      case 2:
        BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context).add(
          const InitializeAccountEvent(
            uiTitle: 'messages',
          ),
        );
      case 3:
        BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context).add(
          const InitializeAccountEvent(
            uiTitle: 'account',
          ),
        );
      case 4:
        BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context).add(
          const InitializeAccountEvent(
            uiTitle: 'shopping-bag',
          ),
        );
    }
  },
);
```

controller page:

```
 Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 20.0.w,
        ),
        child: const BlocControllerProfile(),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

the page where i have the problem:

```
 return SingleChildScrollView(
  reverse: true,
  child: Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => context.read<EditProfileBloc>().add(
                    const GetProfileEvent(),
                  ),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                size: 24.0.w,
              ),
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            Text(
              localeManager.commonTrans('edit_address'),
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.sp,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
              size: 24.0.w,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10.0.h,
        ),

        AddressTextField(
          name: 'recipient',
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          controller: recipientNameController,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
              return localeManager.commonTrans('recipient_blank');
            }
            return null;
          },
        ),
        AddressTextField(
          name: 'address_1',
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          controller: address1Controller,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
              return localeManager.commonTrans('address_1_blank');
            }
            return null;
          },
        ),

        //line 2
        AddressTextField(
          name: 'address_2',
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          controller: address2Controller,
          validator: (s) {
            return null;
          },
        ),

        //country
        DropDownAddressButton(
          name: 'country',
          data: countryNames,
          selected: country,
          onStateChanged: (newValue) {
            setState(() {
              country = newValue;
              getStatesData();
            });
          },
        ),
        //state
        DropDownAddressButton(
          name: 'state',
          data: statesNames,
          selected: state,
          onStateChanged: (newValue) {
            setState(() {
              country = newValue;
            });
          },
        ),
        //city
        AddressTextField(
          name: 'city',
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          controller: cityController,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
              return localeManager.commonTrans('city_blank');
            }
            return null;
          },
        ),

        //zipcode
        AddressTextField(
          name: 'zip_code',
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          controller: zipcodeController,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
              return localeManager.commonTrans('zip_code_blank');
            }
            return null;
          },
        ),
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            //state
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: DropDownAddressButton(
                name: 'contact_number',
                data: phoneCodes,
                selected: phone,
                onStateChanged: (newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    phone = newValue;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10.0.w,
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: AddressTextField(
                name: '',
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                controller: phoneController,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return localeManager.commonTrans('phone_blank');
                  }
                  if (RegExp(r'^[0-9]+$').hasMatch(value)) {
                    return localeManager.commonTrans('phone_invalid');
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: 20.0.h,
          ),
          child: ProfileButton(
            title: localeManager.commonTrans('save'),
            onTap: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                //valid
              } else {}
            },
            backgroundColor: const Color(kPrimaryCOLOR),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            weight: FontWeight.w700,
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: 20.0.h,
          ),
          child: ProfileButton(
            title: localeManager.commonTrans('delete'),
            onTap: () {},
            backgroundColor: const Color(kGrayCOLOR).withAlpha(60),
            textColor: const Color(kPrimaryCOLOR),
            weight: FontWeight.w700,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Please can you post a little more code so we can help you debug your issue?

Comment: i added them now thank you

Comment: Sadly, your code is way too modified to be tested independently but from what I'm seeing is that you're using SingleChildScrollView just above the form. Try adding it before the SafeArea also you can remove the Padding (You can remove the padding and apply the SafeArea left, and right values instead. Under the SingleChildScrollView you can add a Column and Expand the child too. It's not guaranteed to work, but if others solution aren't working its worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

I found success with this solution.

```
Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                 bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom));
```

Comment: saddly that did not workout for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `viewInsets.bottom` in the `bottom padding`  in you `Padding` widget as below:

```
EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
```

Comment: saddly that did not workout for me.

Comment: Can you please include your code in the question so others can try and solve the issue..

Comment: i added them now, thank you